# Caplet "in arrears" pricing formula

Tags: options, option-pricing, interest-rates, numeraire, caplet

The forward Libor rate $L(t,t_1,t_2)$, with $0 \leq t \leq t_1$, must be a martingale under the T-forward measure associated with the zero coupon bond $P(t,t_2)$ **that matures at time $t_2$.**

Pricing a caplet that "matures" at $t_2$ then becomes trivial (i.e. a caplet where the Libor sets at $t_1$ but the payment occurs at $t_2$):

$$C(t_0, T=t_2)=P(t_0,t_2)\mathbb{E}^{P_{t_2}}\left[\frac{(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K)^{+}}{P(t_2,t_2)}\right]=P(t_0,t_2)\mathbb{E}^{P_{t_2}}\left[(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K)^{+}\right]=P(t_0,t_2)Black76(K,L(t_0,t_1,t_2))$$

However, suppose the caplet matures at $t_1$ (which actually seems more natural, because that is when the Libor $L(t,t_1,t_2)$ sets), then we have:

$$C(t_0, T=t_1)=P(t_0,t_2)\mathbb{E}^{P_{t_2}}\left[\frac{(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K)^{+}}{P(t_1,t_2)}\right]$$

It's not immediately obvious how to evaluate this expectation (we could potentially chose $P(t,t_1)$ as Numeraire instead, but then we'd need to come up with a more complicated process for the Libor $L(t,t_1, t_2)$ under this Numeraire than just an exponential driftless martingale process that we use under the $P(t,t_2)$ as numeraire, so that doesn't really solve the issue).

How do we price such caplet? Libor market model?

Comment: This is a Libor in-arrear caplet. Situations like this call for a convexity adjustment. You could have a look at Brigo-Mercurio, “Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice” (2006), sec. 13.8.2 “The Convexity Adjustment Technique”.

Comment: @GabrielePompa: thank you. Any chance you could post the crux of it as an answer pls? I don't have access to that book at the moment.

Comment: Hi it seems to me that you have it reversed.  The caplet expiring $t_1$ And paying out on $t_2$ is easier to price because the relevant forward rate is a martingale, as you point out.  It is the caplet expiring $t_2$ and also paying $t_2$ that is more difficult (the ‘arrears caplet’).

Comment: @dm63: the relevant forward rate $L(t,t_1,t_2)$ that sets at $t_1$ is indeed a martingale, but under $P(t,t_2)$, i.e. a bond that matures at $t_2$. So as of $t_1$, when the caplet matures and the Libor $L(t_1,t_1,t_2)$ had set, $P(t_1,t_2)$ had not yet matured: so it is not equal to 1 yet, and as a random variable, can't be taken out of teh expectation, no?

Comment: Hi - maybe we are saying the same thing however looking at your expression, why is there a $(P(t_1, t_2)$ in the denominator ? This payoff has cashflow at $t_2 $doesn’t it? This has already been discounted correctly.

Comment: And, if the cashflow is at $t_1$ , you make use of the fact that $P(t_1,t_2)   = 1/(1+0.25 L(t_1,t_1,t_2))$ and you can do the integral. If will have some Libor squared terms.  The 0.25 is for 3mo Libor, replace with appropriate accrual factor.

Comment: @dm63: hmm, I am still a little confused, this must be my lack of understanding of the model. I assume the option expires at $t_1$ & the payment happens also at $t_1$. Based on your hint, we need to evaluate the integral: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K)^{+}}{1+\tau L(t_1,t_1,t_2)}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{I L(t_1,t_1,t_2)}{1+\tau L(t_1,t_1,t_2)}\right]-K\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{I}{1+\tau L(t_1,t_1,t_2)}\right]$$ Still unsure how to proceed. Any chance you could post an answer, where you also show what happens when the payment occurs at $t_2$ (but the option still expires at $t_1$).

Comment: Above, $I$ is the indicator $I_{K<L(t_1,t_1,t_2)}$

Comment: @dm63: Ps: The bond $P(t_1,t_2)$ appears in the denominator, because I just 'blindly' applied the fact that $$\frac{C(t_0,t_1)}{N(t_0)}=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{C(t_1)}{N(t_1)}\right]$$ with $C$ being the caplet and $N$ being the numeraire, where we chose $N(t)=P(t,t_2)$

Comment: Hi in a standard caplet, expiration is at $t_1$ a d payment is at $t_2$.  This is why there is confusion on nomenclature.  The case where both setting and payment occurs at t_1 is the arrears caplet requiring the convexity adjustment.  I will try to complete your proof

Comment: @dm63: ok, cool. Happy to put a bounty on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $P(t, T)$ be the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$ and unit face value. Consider the pricing of the caplet with payoff $(L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+$ at time $t_1$, where $0<t_1 < t_2$ and, for $0\le s \le t_1$,
\begin{align*}
L(s; t_1, t_2) = \frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\left(\frac{P(s, t_1)}{P(s, t_2)}-1\right)
\end{align*}
is the forward rate set at time $s$ for the calculation period $(t_1, t_2]$. Let $Q_{t_1}$ and $Q_{t_2}$ be the respective $t_1$- and $t_2$-forward probability measures, and $E_{t_1}$ and $E_{t_2}$ be the corresponding expectation operators.

Note that, for $0\le s \le t_1$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ_{t_1}}{dQ_{t_2}}\big|_{s} &= \frac{P(0, t_2)}{P(0, t_1)}\frac{P(s, t_1)}{P(s, t_2)}\\
&=\frac{P(0, t_2)}{P(0, t_1)}\Big(1+ (t_2-t_1)L(s; t_1, t_2) \Big).
\end{align*}
We assume that, under the $t_2$-forward probability measure $Q_{t_2}$,
\begin{align*}
dL(t; t_1, t_2) =  \sigma L(t; t_1, t_2) dW_t,
\end{align*}
for $0\le t \le t_1$,
where $\sigma$ is the volatility and $\{W_t,\, t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then, the value of the caplet is given by
\begin{align*}
&\ P(0, t_1) E_{t_1}\big((L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+\big) \\
=&\ P(0, t_1) E_{t_2}\left(\frac{dQ_{t_1}}{dQ_{t_2}}\big|_{t_1}(L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+\right)\\
=&\ P(0, t_2) E_{t_2}\left(\Big(1+ (t_2-t_1)L(t_1; t_1, t_2) \Big)(L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+ \right)\\
=&\ P(0, t_2) E_{t_2}\big((L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+\big) + P(0, t_2)(t_2-t_1) E_{t_2}\big(L(t_1; t_1, t_2)(L(t_1; t_1, t_2)-K)^+\big).
\end{align*}
The remaining computations are straightforward, given the dynamics of $L(t_1; t_1, t_2)$ under $Q_{t_2}$.

Comment: I like your solution. Very elegant and therefore better than mine. :)

Comment: Thanks @B_B. I aimed to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: I agree with this.  If you continue this a little further, you can show that it equals $(1+(t_2-t_1)K)$ times the regular caplet (being the first term in @Gordon's answer) plus a portfolio of caplets struck at $K$ and above. (portfolio of caplets produces a $(L-K)^2$ term)

Comment: Gordon, this community would not be the same without you. Pls stay active. For ever :)

Comment: $$=P(0,t_2)(1+(t_1 - t_2)K)E_{t_2}((L(t_1;t_1,t_2)-K)^+ +2P(0, t_2)(t_2-t_1)\int_K^\infty(L(t_1;t_1,t_2)-J)^+\,dJ$$

Comment: @dm63 I think your formula is incorrect. It should be rather $\int_{K}^{+\infty}(z-K)^{2}f(z)dz$ where $f(z)$ is a pdf of $L(t_{1};t_{1},t_{2})$. Note that, your formula is a price at time $0$ and $L(t_{1};t_{1},t_{2})$ is a random variable at time $0$, so it does not make any sense, does it?

Comment: So $\mathbb{E}_{t_2}\left[\left(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K\right)^+\right]$ just evaluates to Black76. And the second expectation can be evaluated by direct integration, using the fact that $$L(t,t_1,t_2)^2=L(t_0,t_1,t_2)^2e^{-\sigma^2t+2\sigma W_t}$$ i.e. $$\mathbb{E}_{t_2}\left[L(t_1,t_1,t_2)\left(L(t_1,t_1,t_2)-K\right)^+\right]=\mathbb{E}_{t_2}\left[L(t_1,t_1,t_2)^2\mathbb{I}_{L>K}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[KL(t_1,t_1,t_2)\mathbb{I}_{L>K}\right]=\\=N(\tilde{d_2})-KN(d_2)$$

Comment: Above, $$N(\tilde{d_2})=\int_{h=k^2}^{\infty}hF_{L^2}(h)dh$$

Comment: @dm63: seems a bit different to your answer. Not sure if what I wrote is correct?

Comment: I’m missing the expectation operator in front of the integral, you’re right.  Other than that it looks ok.  My integration variable is the strike, not the possible values of Libor.

Answer (score 3):

**Case I**

Let us consider a derivative with a payoff $H(L(T_{f},T_{S},T_{E}))$ which is paid at time $T_{p}$.

Note that:

- $T_{f}$ - LIBOR fixing date;
- $T_{S}$ - LIBOR start date;
- $T_{E}$ - LIBOR maturity date;
- $T_{p}$ - derivative payment date.

Also, $T_{f}=T_{S}=t_{1}$ and $T_{E}=T_{p}=t_{2}$ in the question.

In your first case $H(L(T_{f},T_{S},T_{E}))=(L(T_{f},T_{S},T_{E})-K)_{+}$ and the no-arbitrage price is:

$$C(t)=P(t,T_{p})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{T_{p}}\Big[H(L(T_{f},T_{S},T_{E}))|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big],$$

where $\mathbb{E}^{T_{p}}[\ \cdot\ ]$ is the expectation under $T_{p}$-forward measure (with $P(t,T_{p})$ as numeraire) and $T_{p}=T_{E}$.

**Case II**

In your second case the derivative payment date $T_{p}$ is the same as the fixing date $T_{f}$ and the LIBOR has maturity $T_{E}=T_{p}+3M$, so the underling is simply LIBOR rate in-arrear.

To be more specific, in your case: $T_{f}=T_{p}=T_{S}=t_{1}$ and $T_{E}=t_{2}$.

The payoff of the second derivative (fixed at time $T_{p}$ and paid at time $T_{p}$) looks as follows:

$$H(L(T_{p},T_{p},T_{E}))=(L(T_{p},T_{p},T_{E})-K)_{+}.$$

It means, in order to price the derivative we need to change $T_{p}$-forward measure to $T_{E}$-forward measure (keeping in mind that $T_{f}=T_{p}=T_{S}$):

$$C(t)=P(t,T_{p})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{T_{p}}\Big[H(L(T_{f},T_{S},T_{E})|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big]$$
$$=P(t,T_{p})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{T_{p}}\Big[H(L(T_{p},T_{p},T_{E}))|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big]$$
$$=P(t,T_{E})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{T_{E}}\left[H(L(T_{p},T_{p},T_{E}))\cdot\frac{P(T_{p},T_{p})}{P(T_{p},T_{E})}{}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$$
$$=P(t,T_{E})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{T_{E}}\left[H(L(T_{p},T_{p},T_{E}))\cdot\frac{1}{P(T_{p},T_{E})}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$$
$$=P(t,t_{2})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{t_{2}}\left[H(L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2}))\cdot\frac{1}{P(t_{1},t_{2})}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]$$

EDIT:

$$=P(t,t_{2})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{t_{2}}\Big[(L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2})-K)^{+}\cdot(1+(t_{2}-t_{1})L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2}))|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big]$$
$$=P(t,t_{2})\cdot\Big(\mathbb{E}^{t_{2}}\Big[(L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2})-K)^{+}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big]+(t_{2}-t_{1})\cdot\mathbb{E}^{t_{2}}\Big[L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2})\cdot(L(t_{1},t_{1},t_{2})-K)^{+}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\Big]\Big).$$

Look at the **Gordon**'s solution.